# Update rank field based on most popular product

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run an update on the following result set:

```
Row#           ProductRankID      ProductID        ProductCategoryID   ProductTypeID         Rank               Score
1                 3                 11266                 9                 80                 0                 765
2                 14                25880                 9                 80                 0                 656
3                 12                25864                 9                 80                 0                 547
4                 7                 11252                 9                 80                 0                 457
5                 8                 25719                 9                 80                 0                 456
6                 4                 13425                 9                 80                 0                 456
7                 11                25677                 9                 80                 0                 456
8                 9                 25716                 9                 80                 0                 432
9                 15                25714                 9                 80                 0                 324
10                13                13589                 9                 80                 0                 234
11                20                25803                 9                 80                 0                 234
12                17                25715                 9                 80                 0                 213
13                5                 21269                 9                 80                 0                 154
14                10                25867                 9                 80                 0                 123
15                16                25676                 9                 80                 0                 123
16                22                17861                 9                 80                 0                 67
17                19                13534                 9                 80                 0                 55
18                23                13659                 9                 80                 0                 54
19                29                13658                 9                 80                 0                 34
20                21                13591                 9                 80                 0                 32
21                6                 11249                 9                 80                 0                 23
22                18                11253                 9                 80                 0                 12
23                28                11253                 9                 87                 0                 65
24                27                13664                 9                 87                 0                 45
25                25                13658                 9                 87                 0                 14
26                26                13657                 9                 87                 0                 13
27                24                13659                 9                 87                 0                 13
28                30                11252                 9                 87                 0                 12
29                2                 12345                 11                80                 0                 324
```

I want the "Rank" column to be set 1...2..3..4 etc based on each row.  Then on change of the ProductCategoryID + ProductTypeID, I want it to reset to  1...2...3...4 etc.

So the results should look something like:

```
Row#           ProductRankID      ProductID        ProductCategoryID   ProductTypeID         Rank               Score
1                 3                 11266                 9                 80                 1                 765
2                 14                25880                 9                 80                 2                 656
3                 12                25864                 9                 80                 3                 547
4                 7                 11252                 9                 80                 4                 457
5                 8                 25719                 9                 80                 5                 456
6                 4                 13425                 9                 80                 6                 456
7                 11                25677                 9                 80                 7                 456
8                 9                 25716                 9                 80                 8                 432
9                 15                25714                 9                 80                 9                 324
10                13                13589                 9                 80                 10                 234
11                20                25803                 9                 80                 11                 234
12                17                25715                 9                 80                 12                 213
13                5                 21269                 9                 80                 13                 154
23                28                11253                 9                 87                 1                 65
24                27                13664                 9                 87                 2                 45
25                25                13658                 9                 87                 3                 14
26                26                13657                 9                 87                 4                 13
27                24                13659                 9                 87                 5                 13
28                30                11252                 9                 87                 6                 12
29                2                 12345                 11                80                 1                 324
```

Hope that makes some sense?

Thanks,
Richie

Comment: make Row# column as IDENTITY(1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `select`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by ProductCategoryID, ProductTypeID
                          order by score desc, productid
                         ) as new_rank
from t;
```

If you want an `update`, use a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by ProductCategoryID, ProductTypeID
                          order by score desc, productid
                         ) as new_rank
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set rank = new_rank;
```

Comment: Hey, this has worked perfectly, many thanks for getting it sorted so quickly.